# Git: How to permanently delete a local commit completely from the git database

Tags: git

I know about git reset (including --hard), but that doesn't completely remove the commit, it just adjusts the tree. I've explored git gc, but that seemingly never permanently removes a commit, either. I know about filter-branch, but that only removes files from commits, but not commits themselves.

There are a lot of stack overflow questions that circle around this topic, but I can't find a real answer to the question: How to *really* delete a local commit (or series of commits), so that it no longer exists anywhere in the database, as though it was never done at all? If it was a method limited to a branch tip, that would be fine.

EDIT: It was a mistake on my part. I was using gitk and used F5 to view the entire tree. But F5 does an "update" and shift-F5 does a "reload". And the deletes don't actually show up actually unless you fully reload by doing the shift-F5.

Comment: Do a `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: Follow this article and perform the steps. https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: First, origin/master is for remote repositories. Second, get reset --hard does NOT remove commits, contrary to popular belief. If you look at the entire repository tree, they'll still be there.

Comment: Som: That article is about filter-branch, which does not remove commits. It only removes files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to permanently delete a commit from Git's history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010048/how-to-permanently-delete-a-commit-from-gits-history)

Comment: Ahh i am sorry. You could do the reflog, lookup the commit SHA and delete it from history there. Have a look here. http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html

Comment: Do you know `git rebase -i`? Would that help?

Comment: Andrew: Nope, that's fliter-branch. "it won't remove those two commits, but it will rewrite history to get rid of the bulky files from your history"

Comment: Som: I've tried delete the reflog and then doing a git gc. The commit stays.

Perl Dog: That doesn't do it, it just creates another branch (tried that too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your branch looks like this:

```
A   <-- HEAD
|
B
|
C   <-- to be removed
|
D
```

and you want to remove commit `C`, the following command might help you:

```
git rebase -i D     # if you have D's sha1 handy
# OR
git rebase -i C^    # parent of C (which is the same as D in this simple example)
```

Once issued, an editor pops up with all the commits starting from `D`'s children, i.e. `A`, `B`, and `C` in a *todo list*. Simply remove the line with commit `C` in that editor window and save the file.

Comment: That doesn't delete the original commits. They'll still be in there. I tried that exact scenario. The rebase just becomes another branch, but the old commits are still there if you look at the whole tree.

Comment: @Nairebis Where did you look? Gitk? Hit SHIFT-F5 (reload). You told about _local_ commits. Have you already pushed them? Then `push -f`

Comment: GAH! You hit it exactly right... I was using Gitk and used F5 instead of shift-F5. I did a shift-F5 and they vanished. Dammit.

Comment: :-) Nice to hear. But be aware: The commits are still there but you cannot reach them easily if you don't know their SHA1s. They are subject to garbage collection. So run `git gc --prune=now` to get rid of all their traces (or wait for 30 days or so until they are auto-gc'ed).

Answer (score 3):

1. Make the commit unreachable from *any* ref or tag, using `reset`, `rebase`, or even `filter-branch`. (How to use filter-branch to [remove the file from all branches).](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/)
2. Expire the reflog so that the commit is not reachable from there. `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`
3. [`git prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) to remove unreachable objects from the database.  (`git gc --prune=all` would also have done the trick, but `git gc` plain keeps loose objects that are younger than two weeks old).
4. You can verify it's really gone by manually inspecting the git object store. A git object is stored according to its SHA1 hash. THe first two letters of the hash are a directory and the final 38 are the filename inside of that directory.

So if the SHA1 hash of your problem commit is `12345ABCDEF...` then it will live at `.git/objects/12/345ABCDEF...`

To be really paranoid you can find out the SHA1 hash of the specific blob (file contents) that you're worried about and hash it with `git hash-object <filename>`, and then check the DB for that hash.