# Deleted and force-pushed object still show up on other dev's machine

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

1. Someone accidentally commited and pushed a number of large files
2. I have deleted the files by using `git-filter-repo` that rewrites the history (like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61602985/56621) suggests)
3. The `git-filter-repo --analyze` has confirmed that the files are, in fact, removed
4. I used `git push --force` to fore-push the rewritten history to the origin

So far so good

**However**

When the repo is pulled to other devs' machines (using `git pull --rebase`) the `git-filter-repo --analyze` still shows those big deleted blobs/files (not shown on my machine though)

`git gc` and `git prune` do not help.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Colleagues need to fetch and `git reset —hard`. Any merge/rebase will not-remove those files from local commit history. There is very likely an existing question/answer that covers this - shall look for one.

Comment: @AD7six I googled *a lot* before posting. Please post your comment as an answer, will upvote+accept

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084868/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+after+rebase

Comment: Just ran `git reset —hard` - the files are still there

Comment: I also didn’t find one - it’s all about the search terms :). Phd to the rescue though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fetch and reset hard

If a remote branch has changed and you want to match it exactly:

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset —-hard origin/main
```

If there are local commits they wish to keep that’s also possible using [git rebase onto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) - for example to keep commits on `feature-branch`:

```
$ git fetch
$ git rebase --onto origin/main main feature-branch
```

## Why didn’t rebasing just-work?

In the circumstances described in the question your colleagues have the unwanted files in their local clones - merging/rebasing the remote branch will not change that there are commits containing these unwanted files ( and any subsequent push will reintroduce those unwanted files to the remote).

Comment: Note: `git reset --hard <any branch>` (in case the fix isn't affecting `main`).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for that comment, the problem in our case was in fact becasue of the other branches

Comment: Amaze no wonder I thought there must be a similar question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18014262/761202